# PHP | How to var_dump regex with few groups?

Tags: php, regex

My Regex Url:

```
https://regex101.com/r/Ejmy3m/2
```

Should collect information from several values,
But it divides them into groups:

Group 1
Group 2
Group 3

What I want is to present the groups as it should be:

```
Example: 1 1 |FR| TF1 FULL HD
```

Right now it appears on the page in this way:

```
array(2893) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(187) ","live":"1","container_extension":null,"custom_sid":":0:19:2329:442:1:C00000:0:0:0:","tv_archive":1,"direct_source":"","tv_archive_duration":"1"},"1149":{"num":2,"name":"|FR| TF1 FULL HD"" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(16) "|FR| TF1 FULL HD" } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(158)
```

Displays all the text, how can i display only the values?

Regex:

```
$re = '/,"live":"(\d+)",(?:[^,]*,)*?"\d+":{"num":(\d+),"name":"([^"]+)"/';
$str = '{"category_id":"140","category_name":"S\\u00e9rie FANTASTIQUE - AVENTURE","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"138","category_name":"S\\u00e9rie Comedie - Romance","parent_id":0},{"category_id":"135","category_name":"S\\u00e9rie Animation - ENFANT","parent_id":0}]},"available_channels":{"1":{"num":1,"name":"|FR| TF1 HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"1","stream_icon":"https:\\/\\/i.imgur.com\\/LMxTAzY.png","epg_channel_id":"TF1.fr","added":"1487462819","category_name":"Fran\\u00e7aises (France)","category_id":"1","series_no":null,"live":"1","container_extension":null,"custom_sid":":0:19:2329:442:1:C00000:0:0:0:","tv_archive":1,"direct_source":"","tv_archive_duration":"1"},"1149":{"num":2,"name":"|FR| TF1 FULL HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"1149","stream_icon":"https:\\/\\/i.imgur.com
\\/LMxTAzY.png","epg_channel_id":"TF1.fr","added":"1500482845","category_name":"Fran\\u00e7aises (France)","category_id":"1","series_no":null,"live":"1","container_extension":null,"custom_sid":"","tv_archive":0,"direct_source":"","tv_archive_duration":0},"4381":{"num":3,"name":"|FR| TF1 +1 FULL HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"4381","stream_icon":"https:\\/\\/i.imgur.com\\/LMxTAzY.png","epg_channel_id":null,"added":"1521066765","category_name":"Fran\\u00e7aises (France)","category_id":"1","series_no":null,"live":"1","container_extension":null,"custom_sid":"","tv_archive":0,"direct_source":"","tv_archive_duration":0},"2":{"num":4,"name":"|FR| FRANCE 2 HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"2","stream_icon":"https:\\/\\/i.imgur.com\\/RsUe4b5.png","epg_channel_id":"France2.fr","added":"1487462859","category_name":"Fran\\u00e7aises (France)","category_id":"1","series_no":null,"live":"1","container_extension":null,"custom_sid":":0:19:245A:440:1:C00000:0:0:0:","tv_archive":1,"direct_source":"","tv_archive_duration":"1"},"1150":{"num":5,"name":"|FR| FRANCE 2 FULL HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"1150","stream_icon":"https:\\/\\/i.imgur.com\\/RsUe4b5.png","epg_channel_id":"France2.fr","added":"1500482948","category_name":"Fran\\u00e7aises ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

UPDATE for Jeff:

```
$api = "http://king365tv.mine.nu:2103/panel_api.php?username=***&password=***";
$api = file_get_contents($api);
$api = json_decode($api, true);
echo $api['available_channels']['2']["live"] ." ".$api['available_channels']['2']["num"] ." ".$api['available_channels']['2']["name"]."<br>";
```

Comment: What part of string should be the exact output?

Comment: you would do that with a lookbehind

Comment: @revo live, num , and name

Comment: Show the exact substring.

Comment: how about that: `((?<="live":")\d+)+|((?<="num":)\d+)+|((?<="name":")[^"]+)+`

Comment: _BUT_: why don't you just json_decode it and get the values out of the resulting arrary/object??

Comment: or: where is that malformed json coming from?

Comment: @Jeff The way works, but I did notice that I also can with json decode. But if I do with json? How should I attract all values? That over 1000 line name and num

Comment: loop over it, or use them directly: `echo $object['available_channels']['2']["name"];` First make sure your json is valid, right now its a chaos json..!

Comment: better delete that last link. contains sensual information..

Comment: Yes, I delete the previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the json string as json.
Unfortunately this json string is quite malformatted, but I'm sure you can fix that.
With a valid json string you can simply access the values that way:

```
<?php
// I fixed the json quite a lot:    
$str = '{"categories": [
    {"category_id":"140","category_name":"S\u00e9rie FANTASTIQUE - AVENTURE","parent_id":0},
    {"category_id":"138","category_name":"S\u00e9rie Comedie - Romance","parent_id":0},
    {"category_id":"135","category_name":"S\u00e9rie Animation - ENFANT","parent_id":0}
    ],

"available_channels":
        {"1":
            {"num":1,"name":"|FR| TF1 HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"1","stream_icon":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/LMxTAzY.png","epg_channel_id":"TF1.fr","added":"1487462819","category_name":"Fran\u00e7aises (France)","category_id":"1","series_no":null,"live":"1","container_extension":null,"custom_sid":":0:19:2329:442:1:C00000:0:0:0:","tv_archive":1,"direct_source":"","tv_archive_duration":"1"
            },
        "1149":
            {"num":2,"name":"|FR| TF1 FULL HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"1149","stream_icon":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/LMxTAzY.png","epg_channel_id":"TF1.fr","added":"1500482845","category_name":"Fran\u00e7aises (France)","category_id":"1","series_no":null,"live":"1","container_extension":null,"custom_sid":"","tv_archive":0,"direct_source":"","tv_archive_duration":0},"4381":{"num":3,"name":"|FR| TF1 +1 FULL HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"4381","stream_icon":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/LMxTAzY.png","epg_channel_id":null,"added":"1521066765","category_name":"Fran\u00e7aises (France)","category_id":"1","series_no":null,"live":"1","container_extension":null,"custom_sid":"","tv_archive":0,"direct_source":"","tv_archive_duration":0},"2":{"num":4,"name":"|FR| FRANCE 2 HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"2","stream_icon":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/RsUe4b5.png","epg_channel_id":"France2.fr","added":"1487462859","category_name":"Fran\u00e7aises (France)","category_id":"1","series_no":null,"live":"1","container_extension":null,"custom_sid":":0:19:245A:440:1:C00000:0:0:0:","tv_archive":1,"direct_source":"","tv_archive_duration":"1"},"1150":{"num":5,"name":"|FR| FRANCE 2 FULL HD","stream_type":"live","type_name":null,"stream_id":"1150","stream_icon":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/RsUe4b5.png","epg_channel_id":"France2.fr","added":"1500482948","category_name":"Fran\u00e7aises"
            }
        }
}';

$object = json_decode($str, true);

echo $object['available_channels']['2']["live"] ." ".$object['available_channels']['2']["num"] ." ".$object['available_channels']['2']["name"]."<br>";
// -> 1 4 |FR| FRANCE 2 HD

echo $object['available_channels']['1']["live"] ." ".$object['available_channels']['1']["num"] ." ".$object['available_channels']['1']["name"]."<br>";
// -> 1 1 |FR| TF1 HD
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I concluded to prepare something similar. I updated the post. How do I just add a loop? With for each?